# How to install open source Qt libraries 5 binary version for Windows

Tags: qt, visual-c++, installation, qt5

This question is specifically about `Qt libraries 5.0.0 for Windows (VS 2010 406 MB)` at http://qt-project.org/downloads (but I assume it will apply to future 5.x.x versions too), and installing that on a "clean" Windows workstation.

What is needed to get it work? *I am after exact minimal set of download packages, meaning an ordered list of "fully qualified" download names, preferably with links to Microsoft downloads.*

The latest Qt Creator from same download page will be used as IDE, so Visual Studio is not required to be installed, and indeed it would be better if that can be avoided.

My current understanding is, I will need to find VC++ Express, then find SP1 update for it, then find debugging package to get debugger backend for Qt Creator. Not sure if I need a Windows SDK package, or if I can replace VS with some version of Windows SDK. And no, the qt-project web pages do not answer this, the instructions there are pretty vague for this specific scenario (using the binary library download without the full non-free Visual Studio 2010).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Strictly, all you need is the [Windows SDK v7.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) and its [SP1 compiler update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4422). Be sure to install the "Debugging tools for Windows" as well (needed by Qt Creator for debugger integration). This will install the commandline compiler and tools included in VS2010.

As an IDE, you can use [Qt Creator](http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator), which is just awesome for Qt projects and great even for non-Qt projects. Of course you're free to use any IDE you want, it's just that Qt Creator comes with, well, everything: integrated Qt documentation, integrated GUI designer, integrated QML designer, version control integration (svn/git need to be installed seperately).

Alternatively, you will need to find VS2010 Express, and its update, though this will leave you without Qt integration in the IDE (because the free VS versions do not support extensions).

Edit by hyde to add links (tested Jan 2013):

- [Visual C++2010 Express can be downloaded from this page](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads) (scroll down)
- [Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)

Comment: I got the Win7 installation to a state where it refuses to install Win SDK 7.1, so with VC++2010 Express and SP1 for Visual Studio 2010 installed, I can compile and run with Qt Creator, but no debugging.

Comment: @hyde: you should be able to install the Debugging tools for Windows as a standalone package. Check the Windows SDK ISO. It seems they removed all the true standalone installers from their website, so you'll have to go through the SDK image if you can't get its installer to run.

Comment: Tested on another computer, it seems installing just SDK and update will produce `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\intrin.h(26) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ammintrin.h': No such file or directory`, when compiling under QtC. This is fixed by installing VC++2010 Express, so looks like no way around that... So, in addition to SDK links in your answer (for debugger), VC++2010 Express and VS2010 SP1 update are needed, and then updates to this whole mess from Windows Update. Whew.

Comment: You can also use the new Visual Studio 2012 Express For Windows Desktop. You'll get the latest and greatest compiler from Microsoft.

Comment: At the moment there is no binary package for that, and I'm pretty sure Qt libs for VS2010 do not work with VS2012...? And compiling Qt on Windows is a bit of a hassle, many pre-requisites etc.

Comment: @hyde the only prerequisite is `perl` if I am not mistaken. And a simple `configure && nmake` will do for compiling Qt yourself. It's not that much of a hassle, but you do have a point. I will refrain from updating the answer with links to VS2012 `;-)`.

Comment: Also needs Python, and I've been told QtWebKit requires Ruby to compile... Then there are OpenSSL and ICU libraries needed, and I'm not 100% sure the 5.0.0 release source package is fully compatible with VS2012 or if a snapshot version is needed from git.

Comment: @hyde oh wow, they really increased dependencies since 4.8. I'll remember that if I ever attempt a go at Qt5.

Comment: If Windows SDK 7.1 refuses to install, maybe you have newer MSVC++ 2010 Redistributable on your machine than the one comes with the SDK. I've just faced the same problem and I can install the SDK after I removed the redist.

Comment: @hyde: I had the same problem. pram is right. Uninstall "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable", then run the Win SDK installer, then install http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4422, which will give you version 10.0.30319 of the redist.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 and Qt 5.7, I downloaded and installed the following tools:

- [Visual Studio 2016 Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx)
- Debugging Tools for Windows (only check this) in [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)