# Qt Creator 5 - No debugger set up

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I was seted up a compiler to **Microsoft Visual C++ x86 Compiler**, but now i have this error:

***The compiler "Microsoft Visual C++ x86 Compiler" cannot produce code for the Qt version.***
Warning: **No debugger set up**

I guess that i need to set debugger, but i don't know which path to put Debugger tab.

I have installed Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Can you run the project? For that, debugger is not needed. I suspect those are actually two unrelated messages. First is fatal problem: compiler missing. Second is just warning: no debugger so you can not *debug* (but should be able to just run it, both for release and debug builds).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For binary version of SDK, you need MSVS2010, Express version should be ok. SP1 must be installed on top of these too.

For debugging you also need to install Windws SDK 7.1 and SP1 update for it.

Links in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14089968/1717300

---

If you want to use MSVS2012, I think you still have to compile yourself. Instructions:

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building-Qt-5-from-Git

Comment: But i have a Visual Studio 2012 full payed version installed, and i have Windows Software Development Kit too(i have Microsoft SDK Directory), i probably just need to include some debugger path in Tools->Options->Debugger->General

Comment: @user1814358 You need MSVS2010 SP1 compilers to use the Qt5.0.0 SDK for MSVS2010. Are you sure either the SDK version you have (which?), or MSVS2012 provdes *MSVS2010* compilers?

Comment: @user1814358 And to be clear: if you want to use MSVS2012 compilers, you either have to compile Qt5 yourself (need to download quite a few dependencies, but otherwise not very hard, see link in answer), or wait for binary SDK release for MSVS2012, whenever that might come (logically, should not be too long, as MSVS2012 is the "current release" of MSVS).